# How to pass Dynamically generated bundlename from webpack to a pug file which is being rendered by node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, pug

I have a webpack configuration which gives the output in the public folder as
`js/[name].[hash].bundle.js`.

Now I want to use:

```
app.get('*', ,(req, res ) => {
  res.render( 'index' , {key: value} )
}
```

on initializing the application via Express.

My `index.pug` file:

```
html
    head
        title SCAN
        link(rel='icon' href=`${reqURI}/favicon.ico`)
        // Container for React rendering
        #react-container
        div(id='one' data-token=token)
        script(src='/js/bundle.js', type='application/javascript')
```

How to pass the dynamically generated bundle name to the Pug file?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the bundle's file name and pass it to the Pug file:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const bundleFileName = fs
  .readdirSync('./js/')
  .find((fileName) => fileName.endsWith('.bundle.js'));

console.log(bundleFileName); //=> e.g. "foo.1234.bundle.js"

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { key: value, bundleFileName })
}
```

And in the Pug file:

```
script(src=`/js/${bundleFileName}` type='application/javascript')
```

Not sure if there's a better way.